# In accounting we know debit what comes in and credit what goes out

Tags: accounting

In accounting we know debit what comes in and credit what goes out, so if some cash is withdraw from a bank we will get the 
message your account has been "debited" with this amount and if we deposit some amount then we will get the message your account has been "credited" with this amount . So why that message?

Comment: SO is not the platform for such questions anyway.

Comment: This question can be moved to Academia, http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about absolutely nothing to do with software development.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition of 'Debit in Accounting'** An accounting entry that results in either an increase in assets or a decrease in liabilities on a company's balance sheet or in your bank account.

**Definition of 'Credit in Accounting'** An accounting entry that either decreases assets or increases liabilities and equity on the company's balance sheet. On the company's income statement, a debit will reduce net income, while a credit will increase net income.

**In a non-accounting sense, "debit"** is a sum of money taken from a bank account.

**In a non-accounting sense, "credit"** is:
 - a sum of money placed into a bank account. 
 - money available to spend.
 - money available to borrow.

The reason why individuals see debits and credits in the above manner, is that the bank statement presented by the bank to the customer is the bank's view of the account. The bank views money in a chequing account as money the bank owes to the customer, i.e. a liability, and in the rules of accounting, an increase to a liability account is a credit.

> i.e. The credit in non-accounting sense means that now bank owes more
>   money to customer that is the **increase in liability**.

For more [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits).